# Submit Request from JavaScript to solve ReCaptcha in Python

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium, form-submit, captcha

I am Currently trying to log into a Site via Selenium and 2Captcha.

Everything work fine right now except the Captcha.
When I try to submit the request, I get an Error.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import requests, time

user_name = ""
password = ""

api_key = ''

site_key = '6LcZlE0UAAAAAFQKM6e6WA2XynMyr6WFd5z1l1Nr'
page_url = 'https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/m-einloggen.html?targetUrl=/'

def Solver():
    chrome_options = Options() 
    chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    chrome_options.add_argument("disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation'])
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options,service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

    driver.get(page_url)

    element = driver.find_element_by_id("login-email")
    element.send_keys(user_name)
    element = driver.find_element_by_id("login-password")
    element.send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_id("gdpr-banner-accept").click()

    u1 = f"https://2captcha.com/in.php?key={api_key}&method=userrecaptcha&googlekey={site_key}&pageurl={page_url}&json=1&invisible=1"
    r1 = requests.get(u1)
    print(r1.json())
    rid = r1.json().get("request")
    u2 = f"https://2captcha.com/res.php?key={api_key}&action=get&id={int(rid)}&json=1"
    time.sleep(5)
    while True:
        r2 = requests.get(u2)
        print(r2.json())
        if r2.json().get("status") == 1:
            form_tokon = r2.json().get("request")
            break
        time.sleep(5)
    wirte_tokon_js = f'document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML="{form_tokon}";'
    submit_js = 'document.getElementById("recaptcha-demo-form").submit();'

    print(wirte_tokon_js)
    print('')
    print(submit_js)
    driver.execute_script(wirte_tokon_js)
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.execute_script(submit_js)
    time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Solver()
```

This is the Error I get.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'submit')
```

this would be my last approach to solve the captcha.. I tried clicking it, even using the exact position to of the captcha frame to click the box

Comment: That message means #recaptcha-demo-form isn't in the dom

Answer (score 0):

*this is not right way.*

> **submit_js = 'document.getElementById("recaptcha-demo-form").submit();'**

*use this for this code, this is the right way.*

> **submit_js = 'document.getElementById("recaptcha-verify-button");'**